# Open Collection-Editor of property by perform Doubleclick on custom usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls, collectioneditor

Is it possible to open the Collection-Editor of a specific property of my usercontrol (Inherited from Control) by performing a double click on it without having to develop a custom implementation of the Collection-Editor?

I were looking for solutions online but could not find one.

Comment: You have to create a class that inherits from [CollectionEditor Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and override its methods to provide the necessary functionality for your specific collection property.